# How to get data using both params in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to get data when I pass both the params. It should be filtered with status and display the search results, but it is displaying all records with out checking for the status value:

```
const customers = await Customer.findAll({
    where: { id: _.map(users, 'customerId') }
});

if (customers) {
    const status = req.query.activation
        ? await Customer.findAll({ where: { activation: req.query.activation } })
        : customers;
    const search = req.query.search
        ? await Customer.findAll({ name: { where: { [Op.like]: '%' + req.query.search + '%' } } })
        : status;
    return res.json({ search });
}
return response.sendBadRequest(res, 'customers empty!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is a mistake in your code..

```
? await Customer.findAll({name: { where: { [Op.like]: '%' + req.query.search + 
'%' } } })
```

it should be :::

```
? await Customer.findAll({where: { name: { [Op.like]: '%' + req.query.search + 
'%' } } })
```

and secondly instead of running multiple queries you should make an object of where condition and run a single query.

```
var where = {
   id: _.map(users, 'customerId')
};
req.query.activation ? where.activation = req.query.activation : null
if(req.query.search){
where.name = {[Op.like] : '%' + req.query.activation + '%'}
}
console.log('conditions :::::' , where)
  const customers = await Customer.findAll({
  where: where
  });
```